# regex to match double qoutes not followed by odd number of backslash

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to replace double-quotes not followed by odd number of backslash with empty string.

For eg:

String : `"hello \" world \\"` , `"hello \\\" world\\\\"`
Regex : ?
Result : `hello \" world \\`  , `hello \\\" world\\\\`
(after replaced with empty string )

at the same time the `\\` and `\"` are replaced by `\` and `"`
i do that simply with regex`\\` and `\"`

I need the regex to replace `"` not followed by odd number of `\` . I am making a simple parser that ignores the string inside " "
so, somebody help.

Comment: Hey, StackOverflow isn't a free code service. You should at least try to solve the problem and if you get stuck, then we can help you, but we are not going to do all the work for you.

Comment: I know, i searched it in web, and i also tried many regex and with lookaround but, i does not able to get the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex will give you the exact result
it should be + instead of {0,20} but java won't allow that,
So you can put double the maximum expected number of expected \ instead of 20

```
    String text = "\"hello \\\" world \\\\\" , \"hello \\\\\\\" world\\\\\\\\\"";
    String newText = text.replaceAll("(?<!(?<!\\\\)(\\\\)(\\\\\\\\){0,20})\"", "");
    System.out.println("newText = " + newText);
```

Comment: can you explain this regex, because i dont understand why there is two look-behind and 4 backslashes (one in lookbehind and other in capturing group)